# XMLHttpRequest event.loaded behaviour changed?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

Some time ago, I wrote a script that looks something like this:

```
$("#file-upload-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData();
    jQuery.each($('#file-upload')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file', file);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: self.urlroot + '/file/upload',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            //Upload progress
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                    //more stuff
                }
            }, false);
            //Download progress
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                //something similar to above
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        success: function( response ) {
            //stuff
        },
        error: function() {
            //stuff
        }
    });
});
```

And it worked just fine. Today I tried to reuse the code on another page, and I've determined that evt.loaded is no longer tracking how much has been sent to the server, but is instead tracking how much of the file has been loaded into memory *to be* sent to the server. So it goes to 100% almost immediately, because the file loads to memory very quickly, while not giving an accurate indication of how much has been sent to the server at all. I tried updating my code to something like the following, to no avail:

```
$("#file-upload-button").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("button").attr("disabled", true).fadeTo("fast", 0.5);

    var data = new FormData();
    jQuery.each($('#file-upload')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file', file);
    });

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (evt) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        console.log(percentComplete, evt.loaded, evt.total);
        //some stuff
    };
    xhr.upload.onload = function (e) {
        //some stuff
    };
    xhr.upload.onerror = function (e) {
        //some stuff
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "Owl/");
    xhr.send(data);
});
```

In both instances, it shows evt.loaded to be the same as evt.total almost immediately, and then several seconds later based on the size of the file, the upload actually finishes and the response is processed. Any idea how I can fix this to actually show progress on the upload?

Comment: i had a related issue with FormData i solved by moving the meta to GET and send()ing the File.

Comment: Got some code you can share for that? Also I've found that the second way does not detect error headers properly, so I have to use the first way

Comment: the 2nd's onload implies a 200 status, otherwise it didn't load. you can use another catch-all event, _onloadend_ to get success and error in one handler. the code adjustment would be moving the meta into the url, get-style, taking out the FormData loop, then using  xhr.send($('#file-upload')[0].files[0]); to send the binary contents of a single file. you can do more than one ajax if you have more than one file; it's better not to throw away the whole batch because one file failed anyway... anyway, you might be able to fix your progress, this is just something that worked for me one time...

Comment: Hey, did you managed to solve this by any chance?

Comment: I don't remember, unfortunately. I didn't come back to post an answer, so I'd assume I didn't and gave up on it.